# Angular Async pipe with combineLatest always return null

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to use an observable returned by httpclient with async pipe but I always get null. In the network tab I could see the call being made and a value is returned.

This is my code.

app.component.ts

```
isPrivilegedUser$: Observable<boolean>;
isAdminMode$: Observable<boolean>;
constructor(client: HttpClient) {
  this.isPrivilegedUser$ = client.get<boolean>
('http://someendpoint/privilegedUser/someusername');

  this.isAdminMode$ = client.get<boolean>
('http://someendpoint/isAdminMode');
}

get isOperationAllowed$(): observable<boolean> {

  return combineLatest([
     this.isPrivilegedUser$,
     isAdminMode$])
   .pipe(
      map(([privilegedUser, adminMode]) => {
        return privilegedUser && adminMode;
      })
}
```

app.component.html

```
<label>
Is User Privileged: {{(isPrivilegedUser$ | async) | json}}
</label>
<label>
Is Admin Mode: {{(isAdminMode$ | async) | json}}
</label>
<label>
Is Operation Allowed: {{(sOperationAllowed$ | async) | json}}
</label>
```

I always get

**Is User Privileged: true**

**Is Admin Mode: true**

**Is Operation Allowed: null**

I know async pipe emits an initial null but after that the value should change. I am using default change detection strategy and I cannot get my head around the fact that Is Operation Allowed is coming out as null.

Comment: can you try `forkJoin` instead of `combineLatest`?

Comment: aslo u haave a typo `{(sOperationAllowed$ | async) ` missing `i`

Comment: forkJoin makes more sense as you expect to have only single response from both http calls

Comment: Think that the problem comes from getter function. Why not just declare the observable variable and assign the value in the constructor or ngOnInit like how you did for `isPrivilegedUser$` and `isAdminMode$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it's a `getter`, change it to a property (just like the other obersables) and I expect it to work.

```
this.operationAllowed = combineLatest([
     this.isPrivilegedUser$,
     this.isAdminMode$])
   .pipe(
      map(([privilegedUser, adminMode]) => {
        return privilegedUser && adminMode;
      })
```